# How do I use Javascript in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

I have got PHP code to show a JavaScript button to the logged in users and it wont display anything if they are not logged in. But it only gives me a white page? The code itself is working because I've used it before but not with javascript.

```
<div align="center">
    <?php
        session_start();
        if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) 
        { 
           echo "<a href=\"" target=\"_blank\"></a>"; 

        }else{
           echo"<div align="right">
                   <input type="button" onclick="document.title = 'Google';" value="Change Title to Google">";
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: You need to escape the double quotes in your echo. Or put the echoed string between single quotes. After that it might work.

Comment: set error_reporting to E_ALL and display_errors to true to see when things go wrong.

Comment: echo "<div align=\"right\"><input type=\"button\" onclick=\"document.title = 'Google';\" value=\"Change Title to Google\">";

Answer (score 3):

YOUR CODE HAving ERROS with quotes, added `\`,

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) 
{ 
   echo "<a href=\"\" target=\"_blank\"></a>"; 

}else{
        echo "<div align=\"right\">
           <input type=\"button\" onclick=\"document.title = 'Google';\" value=\"Change Title to Google\">";
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to close your php when you don't need it :

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) 
{ 
?>
<a href="" target="_blank"></a>
<?php
}else{
?>
 <div align="right"> ....
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: I suggest more convenient method by using another syntax: <?php if(...): ?> <!--html goes here --> <?php else: ?><!-- Another html --> <?php endif; ?>